# why when I remove specific rows, my output is all NA?

Tags: r

I have a data that I uploaded it here 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0bc36ec5f46757de7c2c

I load it in R using following command

```
df <- read.delim("path to the data", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE, row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='')
```

Then I check for a specific column to see how many + are there like this

```
length(which(df$Potential.contaminant == "+"))
```

which shows 9 in this cas. Then I try to remove all the rows that the + is in that row using the following command

```
Newdf <- df[df$Potential.contaminant != "+", ]
```

The output is all NA. what is wrong ?? what do I do wrong here ?

As @akrun suggested I have tried many different ways to do it but without success

```
df[!grepl("[+]", df$Potential.contaminant),]
df[ is.na(df$Potential.contaminant),]
subset(df, Potential.contaminant != "+")
df[-(which(df$Potential.contaminant == "+")),]
```

None of above commands could solve it. One idea was that the Potential.contaminant has NA and that is the reason. I replaced all NA with zero using

```
df[c("Potential.contaminant")][is.na(df[c("Potential.contaminant")])] <- 0
```

but still the same.

Comment: Try with `grep` i.e. `df[!grepl("[+]", df$Potential.contaminant),]`

Comment: @akrun the same using grep. please check it yourself. when I use grep then only the first column is ok but the rest is NA again

Comment: It's because all the other elements are NA in 'Potential.contaminant'

Comment: @akrun I see, how can I solve that to not take NA from potential.contaminant into account. I only want to remove the rows that have + in that column named "potential.contaminant"

Comment: By reading your data, i get `df$Potential.contaminant
 [1] "+" NA  NA  NA  NA  "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "+"`

Comment: As the other elements are all NA, try with `is.na`, ie. `df[ is.na(df$Potential.contaminant),]`

Comment: @akrun the same gives me NA. I have tried many ways but I don't know why it is not working I even tried with  subset(df, Potential.contaminant != "+") but the same

Comment: @akrun newdf <- df[-(which(df$Potential.contaminant == "+")),] one also did not work

Comment: Because all other values are NA

Comment: The problem seems to come from how you import your data and how it is formed. For example, if you call `rownames(df)` you'll get names that consist of a stream of numbers.

Comment: @akrun so you think there won't be any solution using R ?

Comment: @R. Schifini could be! however I tried different way of loading the data but still was not the case and could not solve it. I think Akrun is right that the problem is NA in that column. but so far I could not find any solution

Comment: I checked the data and there seems to be two types of separators, tabs and semicolons. There is also some text at the beginning of the data that doesn't seem to be column names.  Some sections that contain numbers separated with `;` have an end of line in the middle of a number.

Comment: @akrun  I don't think the problem is NA in that column. I replaced the NA with zero using  the following command but then I get NA after trying to remove those df[c("Potential.contaminant")][is.na(df[c("Potential.contaminant")])] <- 0

Comment: @R. Schifini what is your suggestion then? did you find any solution to it ?

Comment: Check the data with a text editor first. Analyze it, see if it has the data you expect it to have, how is it separated. If its structure is irregular then it may need some previous work before importing it with a simple command. It might not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

copy pasted your gist in a file `c:/input.txt` and then used your code:

```
df <- read.delim("c:/input.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE, row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='')
```

Now:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   21 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Intensityhenya         : int  0 NA NA NA NA 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Only.identified.by.site: chr  "+" NA NA NA ...
 $ Reverse                : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Potential.contaminant  : chr  "+" NA NA NA ...
 $ id                     : int  0 NA NA NA NA 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ IDs.1                  : chr  "16182;22925;28117;28534;28538;29309;36387;36889;42536;49151;49833;52792;54591;54592" NA NA NA ...
 $ razor                  : chr  "True;True;False;False;False;False;False;True;False;False;False;False;False;False" NA NA NA ...
 $ Mod.IDs                : chr  "16828;23798;29178;29603;29607;30404;38270;38271;38793;44633;51496;52211;55280;57146;57147;57148;57149" NA NA NA ...
 $ Evidence.IDs           : chr  "694702;694703;694704;1017531;1017532;1017533;1017534;1017535;1017536;1017537;1017538;1017539;1017540;1017541;1017542;1017543;10"| __truncated__ NA NA NA ...
 $ GHSIDs                 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BestGSFD               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

If I try to subset:

```
> df2 <- df[is.na(df$Potential.contaminant),]
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Intensityhenya         : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Only.identified.by.site: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Reverse                : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Potential.contaminant  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ id                     : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ IDs.1                  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ razor                  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Mod.IDs                : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Evidence.IDs           : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ GHSIDs                 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BestGSFD               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

But your datas are so crazy it's nearly impossible to visualize them so let's try something else to get the glance of it.

```
> colnames(df)
 [1] "Intensityhenya"          "Only.identified.by.site" "Reverse"                 "Potential.contaminant"   "id"                      "IDs.1"                   "razor"                   "Mod.IDs"                
 [9] "Evidence.IDs"            "GHSIDs"                  "BestGSFD"
```

Your header is a pain to follow, let's have a look at it:

```
IDs Intensityhenya  Only identified by site Reverse Potential contaminant   id  IDs razor   Mod.IDs Evidence IDs    GHSIDs  BestGSFD
```

Along with a line of data where long data are cut to get a glance:

```
CON__A2A4G1 0   +       +   0   16182;[...];4592    True;[..];False 16828;[...];57149   694702;[...];2208697;       
208698;[...];2441826                                            
3;2433194;[...];4682766
```

I've just stripped extraneous numbers when possible and sure, keeping the tabs and newlines.

I hope you see how and why this can lead to a proper analysis of your data, do some check on your input data to sanitize them before retrying to load them in R.

For illustration purpose here is your gist with ellipsis and %T% in place of tabs:

```
IDs%T%Intensityhenya%T%Only identified by site%T%Reverse%T%Potential contaminant%T%id%T%IDs%T%razor%T%Mod.IDs%T%Evidence IDs%T%GHSIDs%T%BestGSFD
CON__A2A4G1%T%0%T%+%T%%T%+%T%0%T%1618[...]4592%T%Tru[...]alse%T%1682[...]7149%T%69470[...]208697;%T%%T%
20869[...]441826%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
[...]20%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
00[...]%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
1271[...]682766%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
CON__A2A5Y0%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%1%T%443[...]5777%T%Fals[...]rue%T%464[...]8377%T%21071[...]489947%T%40503[...]780178%T%40505[...]780175
CON__A2AB72%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%2%T%443[...]0447%T%Tru[...]alse%T%464[...]2842%T%21070[...]232341%T%40502[...]250729%T%40502[...]250728
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000014147%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%3%T%53270%T%TRUE%T%55779%T%238286[...]382871%T%457377[...]573778%T%4573776
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024146%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%4%T%186[...]5835%T%Tru[...]rue%T%194[...]8438%T%8382[...]492132%T%15455[...]783465%T%15455[...]783465
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024466;CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024462%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%5%T%939[...]5179%T%Tru[...]rue%T%978[...]7757%T%41149[...]468480%T%78212[...]739209%T%78217[...]739209
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000025008%T%0%T%+%T%%T%+%T%6%T%1564[...]8580%T%Fals[...]alse%T%1627[...]9651%T%66672[...]269215%T%125151[...]439696%T%125151[...]439691
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000038253%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%7%T%120[...]5703%T%Fals[...]alse%T%125[...]8300%T%5326[...]25602%T%%T%
;125602[...]178%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
1[...]483384%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
22838[...]23247%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
;123247[...]411%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
4[...]7%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
603[...]790126;%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
79012[...]13848%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
;413848[...]765024%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%%T%
sp|O43790|KRT86_HUMAN;CON__O43790%T%0%T%%T%%T%+%T%8%T%121[...]5716%T%Tru[...]rue%T%126[...]8315%T%5455[...]484318%T%10404[...]426334%T%
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your data rows which are not marked as contaminants, have no values. The "NA" are because of the "na.strings=''" emplyed during read.delim function call. So for example, if you do:

```
df <- read.delim("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/0bc36ec5f46757de7c2c/raw/517ef70ab6a68e600f57308e045c2b4669a7abfc/example.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="\t")
df<-df[df$Potential.contaminant!='+',] 
summary(df)
```

you should see empty cells.